# Open socket server to clients outside of localhost

Tags: java, sockets, networking

TLDR: Allow people not on localhost connect to my chat server if they have the server IP.

I am starting to learn about socket programming in Java and I have come across an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I have created a basic chat program with a server and a client using sockets. This works perfectly in localhost, but I want to share it with my friends. I have searched for hours and can't really find a solution. From what I've read I need to bind my ServerSocket with my IP or Port forward. Just looking for some clarification and possible steps I could take.

How I'm starting the server

`ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(5056);`

How I'm connecting to the server

```
Scanner readIp = new Scanner(System.in);
 String ip = readIp.nextLine();
 socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(ip), Integer.parseInt("5056"));
```

Posts I've looked at

[Java Socket port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167512/java-socket-port-forwarding)

https://coderanch.com/t/571967/java/connect-machine-localhost

[What does it mean to bind() a socket to any address other than localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39314086/what-does-it-mean-to-bind-a-socket-to-any-address-other-than-localhost/39314221)

Comment: Is the port opened in the firewall on those machines? If there's also a router or something in between you must activate port forwarding to the pc

Comment: Well I guess to begin with, do I need change anything in my code?

Comment: No, as you said if it's working locally, it's only a configuration issue

Answer (score 0):

To 'Allow people not on localhost connect to my chat server if they have the server IP.' and outside of your LAN:

1. public 'white' external IP.

So for example this page https://whatismyipaddress.com/ should display exactly same IP address as displayed in your OS

2. non blocked incoming connections on ISP level: your ISP should allow incoming connections to your computer from internet.
3. some opened port, not blocked by local firewall or by ISP.
   Typically all ports below 1024 are blocked for input on ISP level.
4. No presence of NAT ( exclusions are present but outside of this topic ), thats common for WiFi/3/4/5g home routers.

As you may already understood - thats complicated.

So faster will be to use an external service,like https://portmap.io/ :

it does VPN connection + port forwarding, so knocking on **their** server from internet will actually call your local chat server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what if I want to host the ChatServer on my computer using my home IP and then give that IP to my friends so they can connect to it, would I need to change my code in anyway? Because I attempted to bind my IP to the SocketServer and it threw a connection error.

Comment: Your code is fine.  Your server will be listening on all of the machine's IP addresses, internal and external.  The issue is entirely to do with the network infrastructure, probably involving NATs and firewalls and routers.  Those are generally set up to make it hard for the outside world to reach your computer(s) at home, because that protects your computer from being attacked.

Comment: So I'm still trying to figure this out. I opened the port on my firewall, but my server is running on the ip 0.0.0.0. I did some research which if I understood correctly, this means that my server is open to all internal and external addresses, but I still can't connect to my server or even get a connection refused error when I try to connect using my home IP address.